# Probability of zero-occurrences of a substring within a string

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Let's assume that we have a string **S** of length *n < ∞* which is consisted of an alphabet of 20 different letters. Each letter does not occur with the same frequency. Let's also assume a substring **s** of length *k < n* (k-mer).

So, the question is what's the probability of the substring **s** to not occur within the string **S**?

Comment: Is there a fixed distribution of letters in S

Comment: No, the letters are not evenly distributed

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854039/biology-how-to-find-the-probability-of-randomly-generating-multiple-sequential/854098#854098.  One of the solution is mine.  Seems like in that cast T=0 See if this is very close to what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

The results of the formula that you see in the post that I have referred to!!

[image]

\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{|l|c|}\hline
T & P \\\hline 
1 & 0.278730925452149 \\
2 & 0.059428898295207 \\
3 & 0.008431600808656 \\
4 & 0.000895516555326\\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{align*}